# Redhawk V3 - IDE Not displaying domain correctly

Tags: redhawksdr

On a fresh install of Redhawk version 3 everything appears to be working and interacting with the domain works fine through Python. I appreciate the IDE has been deprecated but I am wondering if there is a fix to an issue when inspecting the domain. When connecting to a domain the IDE is producing the following error

`Failed to fetch profile object from profile path: 'sca:///domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml?domain=REDHAWK_DEV&fs=IOR%3A000000000000001749444C3A43462F46696C654D616E616765723A312E300000000000010000000000000070010102000B00000031302E31312E322E3132000022CC00001C000000FF446F6D61696E4D616E61676572FEDD11376201003E5C00000000000200000000000000080000000100000000545441010000001C00000001000000010001000100000001000105090101000100000009010100#/'`

The full stack indicates it is trying to access a file that doesn't exist (DomainManager.dmd.xml, which doesn't exist), full stack

`org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl$1DiagnosticWrappedException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File cache error: /home/centos/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/gov.redhawk.sca.efs/fileCache/sdr_REDHAWK_DEV/dom/domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.handleDemandLoadException(ResourceSetImpl.java:319)  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:278)   at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:406)    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getEObject(ResourceSetImpl.java:220)     at gov.redhawk.model.sca.ProfileObjectWrapper$Util.fetchProfileObject(ProfileObjectWrapper.java:225)    at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.ScaPropertyContainerImpl.fetchProfileObject(ScaPropertyContainerImpl.java:379)    at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.ScaPropertyContainerImpl.fetchPropertyDefinitions(ScaPropertyContainerImpl.java:708)  at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.ScaPropertyContainerImpl.fetchProperties(ScaPropertyContainerImpl.java:611)   at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.ScaDomainManagerImpl.fetchAttributes(ScaDomainManagerImpl.java:2187)  at gov.redhawk.model.sca.impl.CorbaObjWrapperImpl.refresh(CorbaObjWrapperImpl.java:761)     at gov.redhawk.sca.model.provider.refresh.internal.RefresherSwitch$1.refresh(RefresherSwitch.java:90)   at gov.redhawk.sca.model.provider.refresh.internal.RefresherSwitch$1.refresh(RefresherSwitch.java:84)   at gov.redhawk.sca.model.provider.refresh.internal.RefreshTasker.refresh(RefreshTasker.java:264)    at gov.redhawk.sca.model.provider.refresh.internal.RefreshTasker$RefreshTask.run(RefreshTasker.java:214)    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: File cache error: /home/centos/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/gov.redhawk.sca.efs/fileCache/sdr_REDHAWK_DEV/dom/domain/DomainManager.dmd.xml  at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.downloadFile(FileCache.java:159)    at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.update(FileCache.java:74)   at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.openInputStream(FileCache.java:84)  at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.ScaFileStore.openInputStream(ScaFileStore.java:306)     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor25.invoke(Unknown Source)     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.EFSURIHandlerImpl.createInputStream(EFSURIHandlerImpl.java:249)  at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.createInputStream(ExtensibleURIConverterImpl.java:360)    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1314)    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:259)     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:274)   ... 19 more Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Server-side Exception: null  vmcid: 0x41540000  minor code: 10  completed: No    at mil.jpeojtrs.sca.util.ProtectedThreadExecutor.submit(ProtectedThreadExecutor.java:86)    at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.readProtected(FileCache.java:199)   at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.copyLarge(FileCache.java:187)   at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache.downloadFile(FileCache.java:137)    ... 30 more Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: Server-side Exception: null  vmcid: 0x41540000  minor code: 10  completed: No     at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor26.newInstance(Unknown Source)   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)  at org.jacorb.orb.SystemExceptionHelper.read(SystemExceptionHelper.java:222)    at org.jacorb.orb.ReplyReceiver.getReply(ReplyReceiver.java:456)    at org.jacorb.orb.Delegate._invoke_internal(Delegate.java:1419)     at org.jacorb.orb.Delegate.invoke_internal(Delegate.java:1188)  at org.jacorb.orb.Delegate.invoke(Delegate.java:1176)   at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._invoke(ObjectImpl.java:475)   at CF._FileStub.read(_FileStub.java:66)     at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.ScaFileInputStream.read(ScaFileInputStream.java:84)     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)   at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache$1.call(FileCache.java:203)  at gov.redhawk.efs.sca.internal.cache.FileCache$1.call(FileCache.java:1)    at mil.jpeojtrs.sca.util.ProtectedThreadExecutor.submit(ProtectedThreadExecutor.java:84)    ... 33 more`

Confirmed files exist on Redhawk V2 system, removed and re-added workspace directory

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue was fixed in v3.0.1 - https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/redhawk/releases/tag/3.0.1.

> The effort in REDHAWK 3.0.1 focused on:
>
> - Replace log4j with reload4j in the Core Framework and in the IDE.
> - Resolved bug preventing fei3-generator from generating python code
> - **Resolved bug preventing IDE from connecting to a running redhawk-3.0.0 domain**